# Qt делегат на столбец

Tags: qt, c++

Можно ли применить делегат к определенному столбцу QTableWidget, а не ко всей таблице, и если можно, то как?

Comment: @MorkOFF48: опубликуйте в качестве ответа, потомки скажут спасибо.

Comment: не могу пока ответы на свои вопросы писать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все, спасибо, разобрался
tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(col,delegate)

Answer (score 1):

В функции `createEditor()` анализировать значение `index.column()`. Для необходимого столбца возвращать созданный редактор (`QWidget*`), для других - 0. В любом случае, методы делегата будут вызываться и для других столбцов, т.к. делегат располагается "по-строчно".